# Is it okay to be under-educated compared to the average StackExchange user?

Tags: discussion

I am a high school student. I am advanced in math for my standards. I am a junior in Calc 1. Compared to the average Math Stack Exchange user, I am years behind. Is it okay to post my questions? It seems like most people have negative responses to my questions. I understand that partly it is due to my ineptitude at asking questions; however, I can't help but feel out of place. I also can rarely contribute to answering questions as I cannot find people at my level. Would it be better for me to just avoid the site until I'm better educated or try to fit in where I don't belong?

Comment: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at *any* level and professionals in related fields. ..." it's in the tour of math.SE; (of course, provided that the questions satisfies specific conditions, which again are mentioned in the [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour); and also elsewhere on meta). "Negative response" is subjective: either the questions are ignored, closed as duplicate, ... Thus the answer depends on these.

Comment: Hi there. I wanted to point you to my answer when someone previously asked something similar. But I did it through the "duplicate question" mechanism, because that seemed like the right way, but unfortunately that does record as a "Close" vote. I hope that doesn't come across as hostile.

Comment: Regardless, please go read my answer to that question, and also, you don't have to post questions to participate. Reading other people's questions, trying to understand answers, and up voting good ones are great ways to participate. Yes, the gamification measures, like rep points and medals, don't recognize them, but you can learn a lot of stuff regardless.

Comment: (Also, I'm bad at asking questions too. I've been here at least five years, only asked one question, and it got down voted, and then closed. And still occasionally gets down votes years after it was closed. Don't get too discouraged.)

Comment: There are plenty of users asking questions about intro Calculus, and about pre-calculus topics in algebra, trigonometry, analytic geometry and the like. In fact, there are so many such users, that it sometimes seems like every question about those topics has already been asked & answered multiple times here. My advice would be to brush up on your searching skills, to see first whether the question you want to ask has already been thoroughly dealt with. And read up on How To Ask A Good Question.